# How to remove DocumentFilter text from JTextField on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

```
class MyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException {

    for (int n = string.length(); n > 0; n--) {//an inserted string may be more than a single character i.e a copy and paste of 'aaa123d', also we iterate from the back as super.XX implementation will put last insterted string first and so on thus 'aa123d' would be 'daa', but because we iterate from the back its 'aad' like we want
        char c = string.charAt(n - 1);//get a single character of the string

        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c) || c == ' ') {//if its an alphabetic character or white space
            super.replace(fb, i, i1, String.valueOf(c), as);//allow update to take place for the given character
        } else {//it was not an alphabetic character or white space

        }

    }

}

@Override
public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1) throws BadLocationException {
    super.remove(fb, i, i1);

}

@Override
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int i, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException {
    super.insertString(fb, i, string, as);

}
```

}

I added this in JTextField. Now I want to clear JTextField text on button click.
[image: Text is Not removing after clicking on Reset button]This is how I'm filling form

thanks in advance**

Comment: Why can't you just use `textField.setText("")` in the ActionListener of your button? If you need more help (and in the future when you post a queston) post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. In this case all you need is a frame with a text field and button and the DocumentFilter and ActionListener. We should be able to compile the code to see the problem.

Comment: No if the textbox is filled with letters it is not clearing the field with txtField.setText("");

Comment: Please read the entire comment. Where is you [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is because i used DocumentFilter on JTextField its not removing the text from JtextField. Text will be removed with DocumentFilter remove() method

```
    try {
        txtFirstName.getDocument().remove(0, txtFirstName.getText().length());
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @camickr - any textfield will clear when executed .setText("") upon. An ActionListener should be sufficient.

```
clearFieldsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        txtField.setText("");
        ...
    }
});
```

There is only one reason I could think of why, as you mentioned in your reply to camickr, the TextFields are not being cleared by .setText("").
You might have to refresh your JPanel using:

```
panel1.revalidate();
panel1.repaint();
```